# Negative Dirichlet Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

From Dirichlet Pigeonhole Principle if $p$ is a prime and if $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ are in $(0,p/2)$ then there is a $t\in(0,p)\cap\mathbb Z$ such that $\|(x,y)\|_\infty<\lceil\sqrt p\rceil$ holds where $t(a,b)\equiv(x,y)\bmod p$.

1. Is there no distinct coprime $a,b$ in $(0,\lceil\sqrt p\rceil)$ such that there is $t\in(0,p)\cap\mathbb Z$ with $\|(x,y)\|_\infty<\|(a,b)\|_\infty$?

From Dirichlet Pigeonhole Principle if $p$ is a prime and if $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z$ are in $(0,p/2)$ then there is a $t\in(0,p)\cap\mathbb Z$ such that $\|(x,y,z)\|_\infty<\lceil p^{2/3}\rceil$ holds where $t(a,b,c)\equiv(x,y,z)\bmod p$.

2. Is there no distinct pairwise coprime $a,b,c$ in $(0,\lceil p^{1/3}\rceil)$ such that there is $t\in(0,p)\cap\mathbb Z$ with $\|(x,y,z)\|_\infty<\|(a,b,c)\|_\infty$? Is it possible to increase size of $a,b,c$ to a larger value than $\lceil p^{1/3}\rceil$?

Comment: Do you mean for $t$ in your question to also lie in $(0,p)$? If so, then $(a,b)=(1,1)$ trivially implies the answer is "no"

Comment: Let $(a,b)=(2,2)$ then. For $t=(p+1)/2$, $(x,y)=(1,1)$.

Comment: $(a,b)=(2,4),t=(p+1)/2,(x,y)=(1,2)$

Comment: @Wojowu coprime $a,b$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the OP should have put more thought into the question before asking, rather than relying on MO to do all the work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Observe that $a/b=x/y$, from which it follows that $ay=xb$. Since $a,b,x,y$ are all in $(0,\sqrt{p})$, it follows that the equality $ay=xb$ holds not merely mod $p$, but in $\mathbb{Z}$. Since $a,b$ are coprime, it follows that $a\mid x$ and $b\mid y$. Hence, $\lvert x\rvert\geq \lvert a\rvert$ and $\lvert y\rvert\geq \lvert b\rvert$.

Comment: If $p$ is not a prime does something like this hold at least when $p$ is square free odd and has only $O(1)$ prime factors?